# Can't change monitor to native resolution

Tags: graphics, display, resolution, hdmi, xrandr

I'm using a laptop running ubuntu 14.04 LTE, and I have secondary monitor LG Flatron M197WD, which according to the lg website can run in a 1366x768 resolution. This mode didn't show up in either the 'Displays'  panel, or in xrandr's output.

So I tried adding the mode:

```
$ cvt 1366 768 60
# 1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync
```

which should give me the modeline for height=1366, but instead gives me 1368. Now I still can't set the resolution I want.

Any idea why this happens, and how I can still set my external monitor to 1366x768?

(Btw, i'm using hdmi with intel integrated graphics)